# How can I print array on MASM32?

Tags: assembly, masm, masm32

I have program on MASM32 which solve a simple piecewise-defined function. In pseudo-code it's:

```
if (a > b) x = 2 + b/a
else if (a == b) x = 25
else x = (a - 5)/b
```

I input a, b, h and n. In loop program makes n steps (a = a + h, x = ...) and writes result of piecewise to array. Now I must write function for print array. This is the code:

```
include \masm32\include\masm32rt.inc

.const

    two     dq  2.
    five    dq  5.
    twfive  dq  25.

    enterA  db  "a: ", 0
    enterB  db  "b: ", 0
    enterH  db  "h: ", 0
    enterN  db  "n: ", 0

    InputFormat     db  "%lf", 0
    InputNFormat    db  "%d", 0

    OutputFormat    db  "%f", 10, 0
    OutputFormatD   db  "%d", 10, 0

.data

.data?

    a   dq  ?
    b   dq  ?
    h   dq  ?
    n   dd  ?
    tmp dq  ?
    l   dd  0

    arr dq 50 dup(0) 

.code

    main proc
        FINIT           ; init of coprocessor

        invoke crt_printf, addr enterA
        invoke crt_scanf, addr InputFormat, addr a

        invoke crt_printf, addr enterB
        invoke crt_scanf, addr InputFormat, addr b

        invoke crt_printf, addr enterH
        invoke crt_scanf, addr InputFormat, addr h

        invoke crt_printf, addr enterN
        invoke crt_scanf, addr InputNFormat, addr n

        MOV ECX, n      ; ECX = n = number of loop repetition
        MOV EDI, 0      ; EDI = 0

        FLD a           ; ST(0) = a

        cycle:

            FCOM b      ; compare a and b, result in SWR
                        ; C2 = 1 => incomparable
                        ; C0 = 1 => a < b
                        ; C3 = 1 => a = b
                        ; else   => a > b 
            FSTSW AX    ; SWR to AX
            SAHF        ; ZF = C3, PF = C2, CF = C0

            JP incomparable
            JC less
            JZ equal
            ;else a > b:

            FLD b       ; ST(0) = b, ST(1) = a
            FDIVR       ; ST(0) = b / a 
            FADD two    ; ST(0) = 2 + b / a

            JMP endc

        incomparable: 
            ;

        less:
            FSUB five   ; ST(0) = a - 5
            FDIV b      ; ST(0) = (a - 5) / b

            JMP endc

        equal:
            FSTP tmp    ; ST is empty
            FLD twfive  ; ST(0) = 25

            JMP endc

        endc:
            FSTP arr[EDI]
            ADD EDI, 8
            ADD l, 1

            FLD a       ; ST(0) = a
            FADD h      ; ST(0) = a + h
            FST a       ; a = ST(0)
            LOOP cycle

            ; all code above works perfect

            ; sodom and gomorrah will be here

            inkey
            invoke ExitProcess, NULL

    main endp

    end main
```

So, first I was trying write a function but I had problems with passing parameters to it. I've decided to try put offset to register, push to stack, then pop it and print (at least) a first element of array. But I get many mistakes.

```
MOV EDI, offset arr  ; move offset of array to EDI
XOR ECX, ECX         ; clear ECX (but not increment yet)
PUSH QWORD [EDI + ECX * 8]  ; found this solution (but with dword, not qword) 
POP QWORD [tmp]             ; on stackoverflow, but it is not working :c

invoke crt_printf, addr OutputFormat, tmp
```

Then I tried to replace push/pop operations to mov :

```
MOV [tmp], [EDI + ECX * 4]
```

Nothing. And I can't use only registers because I use DQ (afaik registers are 32-bit, DQ — 64-bit).

I tried a lot of ways (for example FLD/FSTP), but I have only build-errors or incorrect output. Could you tell me the correct solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`PUSH/POP r/m64` isn't valid in 32-bit mode (even if it had been, the correct MASM syntax would've been `QWORD PTR [...` rather than just `QWORD [...`).

But there are other ways to move your data:

- You could use two `PUSH DWORD PTR` instructions that each push half of the data, and then two `POP DWORD PTR` instructions to pop the data into place.
- You could use the `MOVQ` instruction to transfer the data through an MMX register (you'll need to add the `.mmx` directive to the beginning of your assembly file for this to assemble):

  `movq mm0,[EDI + ECX * 8]`
  `movq [tmp],mm0`
  `emms`
- You could move the data using the FPU:

  `fld QWORD PTR [EDI + ECX * 8]`
  `fstp QWORD PTR [tmp]`

Comment: Thanks a lot for explanation! I choose the last way.